# Binding a property of an object of a class inside another doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an strange problem with binding in `WPF`.
There is a simple sample of what i'm doing:

```cs
 public class Project
 {
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
 }

 public class People
 {
   private string _name;
   public string Name
   {
      get { return _name; }
      set
      {
        _name= value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
      }
   }

   private Project _project;
   public Project Project 
   {
      get { return _project; }
      set
      {
        _project= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Project");
      }
   }
}
```

Now I bound a grid to an instance of People in the view and it can bind controls to Project and Name of People class, but I really can't understand why I can not bind to `Project.Title`.

I write my `XAML` code like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<Combobox .... SelectedItem="{Binding Project}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Project.Title}"/>
```

The first two controls above get bounded correctly but the last `TextBox` doesn't. I have no idea why it can access to `Project` but not `Project.Title`? It's an another weird thing I've already seen in WPF!

Comment: Have a look in the output window to see if there are any binding related errors there.

Comment: Actually no!but thank you for reminding me

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a blank project, or update the snippet from above with your actual code. As it is, it should work ok since there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone,but the problem wasn't what i thought.Actually i used [PropertyChanged.Fody](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/PropertyChanged.Fody) to inject `INotifyPropertyChanged` into properties,but it seems it doesn't do what i expected.I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` myself and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your combo box selection is not setting the selected value without using `Mode=TwoWay`:

```xml
<Combobox .... SelectedItem="{Binding Project, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Once the `Project` is set, the  property is set, the `Title` will show.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Path=Project.Title".
Worked for me in a same case.

Comment: I would write it as a comment, but I don't have enough reputaion.

Comment: Wellcome  user2760623!Don't worry about it and i suggest you use anoter clearer Username from begining,because you're gonna like this website,and thank you for the answer,i'll give it a try.

Comment: @user2760623 There is not diffrence between `{Binding Project.Title}` or `{Binding Path=Project.Title}`. Its the same

Comment: I know that basicly it's the same. But when I do it Without "Path=" VisualStudio puts the object ("project" in that case) in red, and the Property ("Title") in blue. And when it's with "Path=" it's all in blue. So I thought there might be a difference.   And as I wrote, I would write it as a comment...

Answer (score 0):

if your DataContext is an instance of your Person object it should work. you can check your bindings at runtime with Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) btw. give it a try :)

you can also do

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding Project, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```